# Weird (or newbie) Python Version behavior and issues installing Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, pip

I'm facing some issues with my recently "python" configuration, i've worked with Python before in Linux based OS's and my older Mac, althou i never had faced those issues before, i've tried to google some alternatives, applied their possible fixes but it have not fixed the issue.

I recently installed Python on my Mac (El Captain 10.11.6) and it supposed to be Python 3.6x or so, althou when i execute `easy_install` pandas is show's

> Using /Users/XXX/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages

I'm not sure if this is alright or not, to be honest.

Another thing is that i've been trying to install Pandas thru homebrew, pip, and a series of alternative methods and i have not been able to so far, a series of different errors have been happening.

```
pip install pandas
```

> OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
>   '/var/folders/5d/49fysh254dj8__50svgj2bmw0000gn/T/pip-q4dR7r-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

> Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 215, in main
>
> ...
>
> > OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
> >     '/tmp/pip-e5bgac-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'

or some other issues like

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/tmp/pip-build-c2a9i3g4/pandas/

Using some other methods

I've also noticed that the Pandas are been installed (trying to be installed) at the 2.7 Python path, which i'm not sure if it's relatable to the issue what so ever.

I've also tried to install pandas in my project thru PyCharm and i got this error:

> distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution
>   for Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.9.0')

I have xCode so for the sake of information.

Comment: Have you tried installing with pip3 at all?

Comment: @AndrewZick Yup! in fact i did: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/5d/49fysh254dj8__50svgj2bmw0000gn/T/pip-build-ayfs2p4m/pandas/

Comment: I know in windows I need to open CMD as a admin for pip to work, maybe there is something similar for Mac, open terminal as sudo root?

Comment: @sniperd heya Snipered, yeah i used sudo too in all those tries, would not work also

Comment: Do you need a newer version of Numpy? Just as an aside, you might want to consider using a package manager like Anaconda to install this stuff for you. It'll save you a lot of time. https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos

Comment: @Ron hey Ron, yup i had, what i've done was solving it downloading anaconda and setup as my project interpreter and all that